# How to restart a tablayout's fragment

Tags: android, tabs

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,true);
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new GetContactsUserFragment(), "User Contacts");
    adapter.addFragment(new GetContactsPublicFragment(), "All Contacts");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the first time I click on the menu, if I load them.
[image]

The second time I click on the menu does not reload the fragments
[image]

I need to reload the fragments, since it does not reload them.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager keeps fragments in resumed state, so there is only one callback you can use. It is a
 `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`.

You should override this method in  GetContactsUserFragment.

And, remember, that when first time your fragment is created in viewpager, `setUserVisibleHint` will be called before onCreate().

**EDIT 1**

You can use it something like that(GetContactsUserFragment.java):

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //fragment is visible now. Put refresh logic here
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is no way to use a set method to overload.